# python asyncpg TypeError: _execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'record_class'

Tags: python, postgresql, rest, aiohttp, asyncpg

So I'm working on REST API using aiohttp & asyncpg. Here is my base view for handlers:

```
from aiohttp.web_urldispatcher import View
from asyncpgsa import PG


class BaseView(View):
    URL_PATH: str

    @property
    def pg(self) -> PG:
        return self.request.app['pg']
```

I'm trying to do a select query for one of my tables and fetch rows:

```
query = select([regions_table.c.region_id]).select_from(regions_table)
regions = await self.pg.fetch(query)
```

However, I get the error from the title:

```
File "blahblahblah/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 583, in fetch
    return await self._execute(
TypeError: _execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'record_class'
```

My guess is that fetch and fetchrow has an argument 'record_class' when calling execute() that hasn't the argument. Here is fetch() implementation:

```
    async def fetch(
        self,
        query,
        *args,
        timeout=None,
        record_class=None
    ) -> list:
        
        self._check_open()
        return await self._execute(
            query,
            args,
            0,
            timeout,
            record_class=record_class,
        )
```

And here is _execute():

```
    def _execute(self, query, args, limit, timeout, return_status=False):
        query, compiled_args = compile_query(query, dialect=self._dialect)
        args = compiled_args or args
        return super()._execute(query, args, limit, timeout,
                                return_status=return_status)
```

But I haven't seen any issue related, and the code from the other project worked alright with the same query. Maybe I miss something on documentation or dealing with these libraries? Any advice is welcomed.

Comment: seems like something wrong with versions of your packages because the actual source of `asyncpg` `_execute` got the `record_class` argument, you can check it here: https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/blob/53bea985bfda80f0af9eb3659f8e4568677e27e8/asyncpg/connection.py#L1613

could you list the versions of your pip packages? `pip list`

Comment: @vadimb I figured out the solution, thank you for the clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to incompatibility between `asyncpg` and its wrapper `asyncpgsa`. The fetch() snippet I pasted above was from asyncpg/connection.py of asyncpg v0.22, and _execute() snippet is from asyncpgsa/connection.py of asyncpgsa v0.16.5, which is now not even a valid version. Version 0.17.0 is compatible with 0.22 asyncpg and its record_class fields, and 0.16.5 is obviously outdated.
So, what I had to do is reconfiguring my requirements.txt:

```
asyncpgsa==0.27.0
setuptools~=54.1.2
```

I'm sure anybody who make venv from skratch won't have the same problem. I used the requirements from the project that was made over half a year ago, so the incompatibility occured. Morale here is: *don't trust copypasta.*